# CSS box-shadow not displaying correctly

Tags: css

The box cast around my "sign in" link has a 1-2px mini shadow shown at the bottom, while I want it to only display on the right. I've played around with my numbers but with no luck.

http://www.aarongoff.com/i

And a minor side question, but how can I get my sign up link to have a 3px margin-left, but my sign in link to stay where it is? (notice how when you select "sign in" and hover over "sign up" the background color of "sign up" touches the "sign in" div.
I tried :last-child, but it wasn't working out.

Comment: Have you tried changing `text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;` to `5px 0px 1px black` (for example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [the `clip` property](http://www.ibloomstudios.com/articles/misunderstood_css_clip/) to only show the part of element which excludes the bottom shadow. Having tried in Firebug, it would be something like `clip: rect(0, 999px, 28, 0)`. Unfortunately, `clip` only works for absolutely positioned elements, so you also have to specify `position: absolute` and figure out another way to keep the link in place.